# Error uploading an image in email wysiwyg

Tags: civimail, drupal, wysiwyg, ckeditor, pantheon

I get this error when I try to upload an image in the email wysiwyg...

Could not load the settings file at: /srv/bindings/34923847/code/profiles/civicrm_starterkit/modules/civicrm/../..//default/civicrm.settings.php

I have no problem uploading images for contacts.
All my directories and resource urls seem to be good. 
I'm running civicrm 4.6.5 on D7. 
I started having this problem once I upgraded from civicrm 4.4.7 to 4.6

Comment: Is your site under /sites/default or a specific folder like /sites/mysite.org?

Comment: No. I don't quite see how that would work though... mysite.org/sites/default ... is what i have.

Comment: if you go into a terminal session and run `nano /srv/bindings/34923847/code/profiles/civicrm_starterkit/modules/civicrm/../..//default/civicrm.settings.php` does it open the file? Just trying to narrow down potential causes.

Comment: Thank you. It does open but it seems empty though. I don't see text.

Comment: So the exact steps are: click Image icon, click Upload tab, click Choose file and select an image, click "Send it to the server" button, receive error immediately upon clicking that button?

Comment: correct. If I click on image info > browse server, I get the same message

Answer (score 2):

CiviCRM Starterkit is installed as a Drupal installation profile, so it's got the civicrm module directory inside /profiles/civicrm_starterkit/modules rather than /sites/all/modules.  CiviCRM is assuming that you can go up two levels from the folder where it's currently running and then over to the `default` folder to find civicrm.settings.php.  That's not the case here.

A couple of things to do, then:

1. To deal with this in the short run, you might copy your settings file into code/profiles/default as a short-term hack.
2. File a bug report because obviously something's making an inaccurate assumption.
3. Consider whether using Pantheon and civicrm-starterkit is giving you any benefit.  Just because something *can* work doesn't mean it's worth the extra effort dealing with a quirky host and an unmaintained distribution.

Comment: Oh, and for my real opinions about Pantheon, see http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/4467/44

Comment: Hey @Andrew Hunt. I pasted a copy of civicrm.settings.php in a defaut folde in civicrm_starterkit directory. The same message seems to show up.

Comment: Another option is that you could create a settings_location.php file and set  the variable CIVICRM_CONFDIR , this can specify where your civicrm.settings.php is

Comment: Sorry, I think i got tripped up on relative paths, and it should be code/profiles/default (corresponding to sites/default when you're in sites/all/modules). Edited the answer above.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error message pop up while trying to run the scheduled jobs via url. Si I dug a little deeper and I was able to fix this by adding the custom code from the civicrm starterkit which is in these files:

Config.civicrm.php
session.php
Drupal.php

It's a little lengthy to describe each edit but if you download the starte
rkit and a regular version of civicrm 4.4.7 you can vimdiff those files I mentioned and paste the custom starterkit code in your civicrm files it should work. 
A little messy but it did the trick