# Fatal error in live site alone : Call to a member function getStatus()

Tags: civievent

This error happen while adding participant to an event 
Error msg : Call to a member function getStatus() on a non-object/srv/bindings/5553047fd8da4cc7a7117aba06fb3fda/files/civicrm/templates_c/en_US/%%C6/C6B/C6B24099%%status.tpl.php:6

Comment: Check after clearing the cache

Comment: It looks like you're hosting on Pantheon - you might be interested in [this question](http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/4464/what-is-required-to-run-civicrm-on-pantheon) and [others relating to CiviCRM on Pantheon](http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/search?q=pantheon).